# Очередность выполнения в jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Использую слайдер Slick, есть кнопка сворачивания слайдера в мини версию, там должен показываться 1 слайд вместо трёх, в jQuery сделал обработчика нажатия, после которого должна меняться переменная с количеством слайдов, а затем в зависимости от этой переменной должен меняться слайдер. 
Но есть проблема, слайдер берет стандартное значение и потом уже не перерисовывается. 
Еще плохо знаю JS, только начала изучение.
Пример - http://jsfiddle.net/3fxwLvL2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var slidesToShow = 3;

    $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: slidesToShow,
        focusOnSelect: true
    });

    $('.hide').click(function() {
        slidesToShow = 1;

        $('.show').click(function() {
            slidesToShow =3;
        })
    })
```

Comment: [смотрите в справке метод slickSetOption](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick)

Answer (score 1):

Не работал со слайдером slick но из вашего кода могу сказать, что после того как вы меняете знаение переменной, вы никак не сообщете об этом сладеру (сам узнать он это не может), то есть так

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var slidesToShow = 3;

    $('.slider-nav').slick({ // запустили слайдер
        slidesToShow: slidesToShow,
        focusOnSelect: true
    });

    $('.hide').click(function() { // обработчик некий
        slidesToShow = 1; // сменили значение

        $('.show').click(function() {
            slidesToShow =3; // сменили значение
            // А вот где то тут надо сообщить слайдеру, что значение изменено
            // быть может перезапустить его
        })
    })
```

Как сообщить слайдеру, что значение сменилось думаю вы пожете узнать из документации к нему.

Comment: _это более современный метод_ - это **абсолютно** одно и то же. Последний абзац лучше совсем убрать

Comment: @Grundy да верно.